# Testing Annotation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, maven-2, testng

I have about 50 testcases in 1 testclass and some are dependant testcases. I struggled to use testng annotation to make them run the way I want. I want the output of the test to be: run1, run 2, run 3, run 4, run 5, run 6, run 7, run8. I know my annotation is wrong because it doesn't run in that order. The priority1 and priority2 run before their dependent test.

Any Help will be very much appreciated.

my testclass looks like this:

```
public class Help {

@BeforeTest
public void aa() {
    System.out.println("run 1");
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void bb() {
    System.out.println("run 2");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "bb" })
public void cc() {
    System.out.println("run 3");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "cc" })
public void dd() {
    System.out.println("run 4");
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void ee() {
    System.out.println("run 5");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "ee" })
public void ff() {
    System.out.println("run 6");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "ff" })
public void gg() {
    System.out.println("run 7");
}

@AfterTest
public void hh() {
    System.out.println("run eight");
}
}
```

Comment: make sure your code is well formatted to make it easier understandable

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you think you need to have such complicated dependencies between your tests?

Comment: What's wrong with the format of the code please?

Comment: @Jägermeister, is because of  my companies business logic.

Comment: Well, maybe you have done that before; but still: have you thought if your business logic has to be like that? You know, when things need to be done in a certain order ... and all the "clients" dealing with such an "API" have to know about this order ... that is typically an indication for design improvements.

Comment: @Sam Is it that the functionality you are testing must be called in a particular order or is it that you have coded your tests to depend on the "setup" from another test? You should try to have your tests be runnable independently from one another.

Comment: @Dennis, the functionality am testing are dependant on each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNG will always run those methods first which are independents. So you can solve the problem if you put them in two different classes like (aa,bb,cc,dd) and (ee,ff,gg) or modify `ee()` to depends on the `dd()` method.

Comment: thanks for your help. It  run in that order but I added always run=true to the independents ee() and dd() just incase any of the dependants (aa,bb,cc,dd) and (ee,ff,gg) fails.